# How to host WSO2 API manager?

Tags: api, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have tried out WSO2 api manager with my api in my localhost. Now I'm looking for a way to host api manager. In local host I can start WSO2 server by running wso2server.bat and so that it will open a console. So in a real server(not in localhost) do I still need to run the wso2server.bat and let the console to be opened forever. Is that the way we can use WSO2 Api manager ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run it as a windows service using YAJSW.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM220/Installing+as+a+Windows+Service